# How to keep track of "Examples" in a math document

Tags: amsmath, theorems, amsthm

I'm not sure if this has already been asked, but I have been curious if `amsthm` also contains support for "examples".

For example, I would like to have something like

```
\begin{example} 
 ...
 \end{example}
```

that gets auto numbered in the same way as theorems, lemmas, remarks, etc.

Is there any `LaTeX` package that supports this?

Comment: `\newtheorem{example}{Example}`, out of the box with `LaTeX` or with `amsthm` then. It will define a counter `example`, is numbered and can be referred to

Comment: If you prefer some eye-candy, look for `mdframed` and `tcolorbox`, both provide theorem environments with colour etc. There are certainly more packages that define `theorem` - like environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three short example definitions from `amsthm`, `tcolorbox` and `mdframed`. See the different options and the similarities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheorem{amsexample}{Example from amsthm package}[section] % Defines a counter named amsexample which resets with section

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=section]{tcbexample}{Example from tcolorbox}{%
  colback=white!90!yellow,
  colbacktitle={yellow}, 
  coltitle={black}
}{exa}

\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=cyan]{mdfexample}{Example from mdframed package}[section]



\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{amsexample}
  Some example.
\end{amsexample}

\begin{tcbexample}{This is my example title}{first}
  Some example.
\end{tcbexample}

\begin{mdfexample}[MDF example title]
  Some example.
\end{mdfexample}

See \ref{exa:first} for more eye-candy. 


\end{document}
```

[image]